# creating a slideshow in android studio

Tags: android

i'm a beginner and i have this final year project where i should build a hotel android app 
i wanted to make the user's interface look better so i tried to make a slideshow where images keep changing without hitting any button + 2 buttons on the sides in case the user wants to change images manualy too

just like in this link: http://www.lemeridienetoile.com/fr

i found a couple codes but not exactly what i wanted 
this really is important so i'll appreciate it if you can help me with the code 
thank you

Comment: You can look for `ViewPager` or `ViewFlipper`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very useful library that lets you do this: [android-slideshow-widget](https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-slideshow-widget)

And [Here](http://androidmirchi.com/android-image-slideshow-tutorial-using-viewpager/) you can find a useful tutorial made using [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

For handle the "next" and "back" buttons you can do something like this:

```
 yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      yourViewPager.setCurrentItem(page, smoothScroll);
   }
});mViewPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage + 1, true);
```

Comment: i downloaded the code from the link you posted but when i open it i get errors in all the instructions that contains (R.) with (R) in red  for example: R.layout.activity_main  do you know how to fix that error, thank you

Comment: Edit your question and add the error log and the code.

Answer (score 1):

This is also another way of creating a slideshow. You can import your images/gifs to your drawable folder and combine it in an array and use the SliderAdapter/SliderView.

Ex:

```
SliderView sliderView;
int[] images = {R.drawable.img1,
        R.drawable.img2,
        R.drawable.img3};
```

the add this to your onCreate()

```
    sliderView = findViewById(R.id.img_sliderView);

    SliderAdapter sliderAdapter = new SliderAdapter(images);

    sliderView.setSliderAdapter(sliderAdapter);
```

//For added animation

```
    sliderView.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimationType.WORM);
    sliderView.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.DEPTHTRANSFORMATION);
    sliderView.startAutoCycle();
```

//Then this on your XML Layout File

<com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView

```
    android:id="@+id/img_sliderView"

    android:layout_width="200dp"

    android:layout_height="250dp"

</com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderView>
```